# Moving a child theme over from a dev site to live

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a dev site and a live site both with the same theme.
I want to move the changes I did to the dev site over to the live site.

Should I just overwrite the child/parent themes via ftp?

Comment: You shouldn't have to change or overwrite the parent theme at all, the entire point of a child theme is to leave the parent theme untouched.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't overwrite the entire theme, just the files you modified or added, assuming you just modified the style.css and page templates. Also, always create a backup before overwriting files.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes, you can rename the child theme in the dev site, and move it over.  This way nothing is overwritten on production, and to test, you just change your theme in appearance - themes.

If all is well, you can overwrite the original or clone the original and then overwrite.